how to deal with prime number and mod operation?
I had list of equivalent relations that for prime numbers in mod operation.
for example its easy to prove that for prime $p$
$$ p\equiv 1   \mod2   \space \space \space \space\space \space\space \space\space \space, p\ne2 $$
$$ p\equiv \pm 1   \mod3   \space \space \space \space\space \space\space \space\space \space, p\ne3 $$
$$ p\equiv \pm 1   \mod4   \space \space \space \space\space \space\space \space\space \space, p\ne2 $$
$$ p^2 \equiv \pm1   \mod5  \space \space \space \space\space \space\space \space\space \space, p\ne 5 $$
$$p\equiv \pm1   \mod6  \space \space \space \space\space \space\space \space\space \space, p\ne2,3$$
$$p^2\equiv 1   \mod8 \space \space \space \space\space \space\space \space\space \space, p\ne2$$
$$p^2\equiv \pm1   \mod10 \space \space \space \space\space \space\space \space\space \space, p\ne2,5$$
$$p^2\equiv 1   \mod12 \space \space \space \space\space \space\space \space\space \space, p\ne2,3$$
$$p^2\equiv 1   \mod24 \space \space \space \space\space \space\space \space\space \space, p\ne2,3 $$
but I have more difficult problems and dont have  an idea to prove
for example let $p$ prime number then
$$ p^8+p^4 \equiv 2   \mod18 \space \space \space \space\space \space\space \space\space \space, p\ne 3$$
$$ p^8+10p^4 \equiv 11   \mod32 \space \space \space \space\space \space\space \space\space \space, p\ne 2 $$
$$ p^8+3p^4 \equiv 4   \mod50 \space \space \space \space\space \space\space \space\space \space, p\ne 5$$
$$ p^4+4p^2 \equiv 5   \mod72 \space \space \space \space\space \space\space \space\space \space, p\ne 2,3$$
$$ p^8+8p^4 \equiv 9   \mod200 \space \space \space \space\space \space\space \space\space \space, p\ne 2,5$$
$$ p^4+10p^2 \equiv 11   \mod288 \space \space \space \space\space \space\space \space\space \space, p\ne 2,3$$
$$ p^4+22p^2 \equiv 23   \mod1152 \space \space \space \space \space\space \space\space \space\space \space, p\ne 2,3 $$

Are you aware of the Chinere remainder theorem?

The ideas in this question lead naturally to the Chinese remainder theorem, the wheel sieve/wheel factorization, and Fermat's little theorem. And naturally lead to quadratic (and higher) reciprocity. Looking at Cox's Primes of the Form $x^2 + n y^2$ would probably also be interesting.

@BenGrossmann yes I know that but how to deal with prime numbers ?

E.g., prime numbers besides $2$ and $3$ are $\equiv\pm1\pmod6$

EG For the last one, since $1152 = 2^7 \times 3^2$, show that  $p^4 + 22 p^ 2 \equiv 23 \pmod{2^7}$ and $ p^4 + 4 p^2 \equiv 5 \pmod{3^2}$.  You can either check every relevant residue class, or think about how to prove it. EG Why is $(p^2 - 1)(p^2+23)$ going to be a multiple of $2^7$?

For the last one, can you show $2\mid\frac{p^2-1}8\left(\frac{p^2-1}8+3\right) $ and $3\mid p^2-1,p^2+23$?  (I was typing this when Calvin Lin's comment appeared)

Polynomial remainder theorem, fermat's little theorem, freshmans dream,  etc.

For most of these, you can gain some insight through a combination of factorising the polynomials and applying some form of the Chinese remainder theorem.
For example, let's look at the first one. First, we can note that $p^8 + p^4 \equiv p + p \equiv 0 \mod 2$, and also since $\varphi(9) = 6$ we have
$$\begin{eqnarray} p^8 + p^4 & \equiv & p^2 + p^4 & \mod 9 \\
& \equiv & p^2(p^2 + 1) & \mod 9
\end{eqnarray}$$
Then, since for $p \neq 3$ we have $p = 3k \pm 1$, that gives
$$\begin{eqnarray} p^2 & = & (3k \pm 1)^2 \\
& = & 9k^2 \pm 6k + 1 \\
& \equiv & \pm 6k + 1 & \mod 9 \\
\implies p^2(p^2 + 1) & \equiv & (\pm 6k  + 1)(\pm 6k + 2) & \mod 9 \\
& \equiv & 36k^2 \pm 18k + 2 & \mod 9 \\
& \equiv & 2 & \mod 9
\end{eqnarray}$$
So $p^8 + p^4 \equiv 0 \mod 2$ and $\equiv 2 \mod 9$, which you can apply the CRT to to get $p^8 + p^4 \equiv 2 \mod 18$.

nice! thank you
